# Grafana: $__timeGroup with dateadd()

Tags: sql-server, grafana

Given a Grafana panel with the following (part of an) sql query on an SQL-server database:

```
SELECT $__timeGroup(DATETIME_FIELD, $aggr_interval)  -- $aggr_interval = '7d'
FROM MY_TABLE
```

which is translated into the following SQL query (according to the "Query inspector"):

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', DATETIME_FIELD)/604800)*604800
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Now, I'd like to add a number of seconds to the `DATETIME_FIELD` before passing it to `$__timeGroup`:

```
SELECT $__timeGroup(DATEADD(second, 10, DATETIME_FIELD), $aggr_interval)
FROM MY_TABLE
```

However, this results in a failure: `interpolation failed: error parsing interval 10` even though the sql query would be acceptable to the sql server - if it would be generated. This is what should be generated:

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', DATEADD(second, 10, DATETIME_FIELD))/604800)*604800
FROM MY_TABLE
```

How to pass the `DATEADD` function as a parameter to `$__timeGroup`?

Comment: Have you tried ` + 1./24/60/6` instead `DATEADD`? It's highly likely that gafana is not ready for commas inside  `$__timeGroup`

Comment: @markalex Good point with Grafana having difficulties with commas. Using the `+ 1./n` syntax works to some extent with normal `DATETIME` fields, but not with `DATETIMEOFFSET`: `datetimeoffset is incompatible with numeric` - sorry for not mentioning the exact field type in the question. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [markalex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75863799/606662) there is a solution using a subselect in the from clause, which prepares the data:

```
SELECT $__timeGroup(a.mdate, $aggr_interval)
FROM MY_TABLE
inner join (select id, DATEADD(second, 10, DATETIME_FIELD) as mdate from MY_TABLE) as a on a.id = MY_TABLE.id
```

The subselect is correlated with the main query with the id column so that the subselect provides one and the same record for every main query record, in order to achieve the goal of preparing a modified value for `DATETIME_FIELD`.

**Bigger picture: Full Grafana panel query**

Although not part of the posted question, `$__timeGroup` is often used as x-axis value in a Grafana time-series query. Here is how it's being used in a query that provides x-axis value, y-axis value and metric name:

```
SELECT $__timeGroup(mdate, $aggr_interval) as time, count(*), 'Metric name' as metric
FROM MY_TABLE
inner join (select id, DATEADD(second, 10, DATETIME_FIELD) as mdate from MY_TABLE) as a on a.id = MY_TABLE.id
WHERE $__timeFilter(DATETIME_FIELD)
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(mdate, $aggr_interval) order by 1
```

Comment: I believe you've over-complicated this query with join a bit. You don't need join, you can apply `where` fully inside the inner query, count and group - outer. I've updated my answer to better reflect your exact case.

Comment: @markalex You may be right, but on the SQL Server version 2019 in use the short version you suggest is syntactially not accepted. Thank's a lot - your detailed answer may be useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

Grafana has trouble parsing content inside `$__timeGroup`: a comma inside your expression throws it off. As a result, it thinks that `10` is the second parameter of `$__timeGroup`. Most likely parentheses are not welcome too.

AFAIK, there is no way to escape the expression passed inside `$__timeGroup`. You'll need to avoid commas and parentheses.

The simplest way is to use an expression like `DATETIME_FIELD + 1./24/60/6` instead `DATEADD`, if possible.

if treating `DATETIME_FIELD` as a number is not possible - you'll need to use a sub-query to prepare your data. For your example something along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT $__timeGroup(mdate, $aggr_interval) 
FROM (SELECT DATEADD(second, 10, DATETIME_FIELD) mdate
        FROM MY_TABLE)
```

EDIT:
Updated query for exact case of OP:

```sql
SELECT $__timeGroup(mdate, $aggr_interval) as time,
       count(*) as value,
       'Metric name' as metric
FROM (SELECT id, 
             DATEADD(second, 10, DATETIME_FIELD) as mdate from MY_TABLE
       WHERE $__timeFilter(DATETIME_FIELD)
)
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(mdate, $aggr_interval)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: The approach using a subquery in the FROM clause works - with a few adaptations, most notably the subquery needs to be related to the outer query so that the subquery reads one record only per outer query record. I'll post a separate answer based on your groundwork.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I created a new column to do the `time_add`.

```sql
Select 
  $__timeGroup(Date, '3m', 0) as time,
  count(rows),
  date_add(Date, interval 1 day) as time2
From table
```

To display the time series graph you have to add a transformation Organize fields and hide the time column.